# A message before new users post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users

Almost all the time, new users post a question with no explanation with no context given, and no mathjax used. I have written "Please write what you tried" a countless number of times. There should be a popup or message that asks new users to confirm that the met all of the following requirements before posting:

> - Did you add [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) to your question?
> - Did you [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q) to see if your question has an answer already?
> - Did you use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Maybe there can even be a requirement that users open the [Mathjax page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) before posting a question. I know some users will skip through all of this like they skipped through [the advice page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice?) that new users [get before asking a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/show-how-to-ask-advice-before-a-new-user-asks-a-question), but I believe this will improve the quality of new posts on the site. Also, an idea is to only make the "proceed" button available after they have checked the box and reviewed their question for at least 10 seconds.

Comment: BTW it should be pointed out that probably correct question should be not asking "What have you tried?" but "Could you add context to your question?" See: [Can we stop the “Show your work craze”?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/can-we-stop-the-show-your-work-craze)

Comment: I was not entirely sure what you meant by "Does your question have an answer?". But I guess that you mean whether the user have searched whether answer to their question has already been posted on the site.

Comment: And quid pro quo, perhaps we should suggest a pop-up message for users posting an answer so that before being allowed to post, they must read the SE "be nice" policy, and click on an icon that says [I understand] before being allowed to proceed?

Comment: [Be nice](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)!

Comment: "There should be something asks new users to confirm that the met all of the following requirements before posting:" But that seems *exactly* what the advice page does. There even is a check box to tick "thanks, I will keep these tips in mind when asking "It is pretty unclear to me what you want to propose. A second check box? Saying, 'I did not just blindly check the first one'? Likely, not. But what do you want to propose?

Comment: @MartinSleziak I personally hold the "What have you tried?" question when the answer seems somewhat easy and that whatever the OP may have tried, there were probably only a few steps away.  It also promotes new-users to realize that we are not a homework site, but an actual Q/A site.

Comment: I edited the main post; would like feedback and suggestions about my idea.