# Make new users feel a bit more involved when they first submit a question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

Very simple thought triggered by the overwhelming amount of new users who clearly haven't read the excellent threads [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and [how-to-ask-a-homework-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question): it would perhaps be a good idea to include a "please read this before submitting" kind of feature, that actually prevents new users from submitting until they have, say, clicked the link. This would make them feel more involved in the task and overall reduce the amount of poorly-written questions.

Comment: AFAIK every new user is shown [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice) before asking first question. Notice that it contains link to [How to ask a good question? - section Provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#9960) It was implemented based on this feature request: [Show “how to ask” advice before a new user asks a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21512). (I am not sure whether there is something for posting first answers, but I guess you are talking mainly about questions by new users.)

Comment: However, there is no requirement that the user has to click on all links displayed in the advice page. They just have to check the checkbox saying "thanks, I will keep these tips in mind when asking".

Comment: and, once having clicked the checkbox, they have agreed that that they are pre-informed, before posting a poor question. Hence clicking in the box, they accept responsibility to heed the advice, or risk closure and deletion.  Cool, good to know.  So newbies aren't so "new" (they nor other users defending such users, cannot claim ignorance to site expectations about asking.)  Or they can claim ignorance, but the ignorance cannot be a legitimate excuse, having acknowledged suggestions before submission. If they chose not to read them, but clicked the box anyway, that's on the asker.