# Who is responsible for maintaining the help pages?

Tags: support, help-center

Who are the authors and maintainers of pages such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? How does one contact them to suggest particular emendations?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/  Make a feature request.  I'd support some more site-specific "how to ask a good question" suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Most pages, including this one, of the help center are the same over most sites and are maintained by SE staff.

You could use "Contact" in the footer or create a feature-request on this or the main meta.

There are only a few pages that are editable by per-site moderators. For those, you could create a meta thread here or ask us in chat about it.

[I am not sure if there is a handy list to know which is which. You could always ask us in chat first. Another test can be to check if the page is identical on several other sites. If it is it is likely not per-site editable.]

Comment: Is the one to which I linked maintained by moderators of this site?

Comment: No. Maybe it was a clumsy way to put it but I said (added emphasis): "Most pages, *including this one,* of the help center are the same over most pages and are maintained by SE staff."

Comment: @quid IIRC even some of the pages that are not mod-editable were discussed here on meta and the moderators passed the suggestion to the SE team. This is example I can give from the top of my head (maybe there were some other similar discussions): [Show “how to ask” advice before a new user asks a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21512)

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes, there is nothing wrong with discussing or requesting it here. (I proposed it explicitly in my answer.) Still, these changes cannot be made by us locally.