# Blocking to ask a question for a beginner.

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users, tour

Is it possible to block to ask a question for a beginner who has not take the [Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: The only indicator that someone has "taken" the [tour] is the Informed badge. However, someone who has the badge does *not* always mean that they have really *read* the tour (they can just scroll to the bottom, just like EULA dialog box).

Comment: Yes, they should stay there at least 5 minut to really read it. That could be arranged?

Comment: I assume it'd be technically possible, but first that would be arguably annoying and second people that don't want to read it won't read it anyway. We have the page I linked, there is a check box and people confirm that they will keep some advice in mind. Then they don't, at all, and claim to be completely confused what happens.

Comment: I think we need a way to set alerts for keywords based on new users. I just found out yesterday that one student of mine asked all his assignment questions on here without even attempting them first. Luckily, only one question was fully answered for him by someone, said person was then scolded by the rest of the community for doing someone's homework for them. That said, a feature that does prevent homework type questions from new members would be very useful.

Comment: @Ken: The easiest way is to make all not-in-class assignments have zero contribution to the final grade. Suddenly the cheating is eliminated, and the lousy questions here don't show up. Of course, I also think heavier penalty should be given to those who ask poor questions, and to those who answer them, but so far too few users here care about site quality.

Comment: @MariaMazur: Why are you answering extremely poor questions [like this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3159081) instead of educating the new users?

Comment: @user21820  Why, she/he has an informed badge. That is my issue. There are  thousands of them dont have it.

Comment: You're evading my question. You chose to answer an extremely poor question, instead of pointing them to the how-to-ask page (which the asker obviously did not follow) and closing the question.

Comment: Why don't you write it as another question in another thread. That is completly different question than this one here. Who are you to call me out? @user21820

Comment: I mention it simply because it's contradictory to your apparent intention in **this** thread.

Comment: @user21820 The only problem with that scenario is that the students don't do any work at all. They are extremely lazy, as evident with them not even doing the assignments themselves.

Comment: @Ken: Why is that a problem? There's no need to make good students do homework, and there's no reason to let bad students pass the course. Lazy people will generally continue to be lazy in real jobs with real consequences for other people, and I sure don't want to become a victim of [shoddy work in real life](https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2018/mar/15/munilla-construction-management-figg-bridge-engine).

Comment: @quid  Well if they don't have a choise then they have to. And if they are confused then perhaps they should not be here either. Make them read and we will need no more review queses.

Comment: @Aqua I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but the issue is that with all kinds of lengthy TOS, cookie-settings, licence agreements, etc people got quite used to and versatile at navigating quickly through hoops without actually taking in much information in the process. It's somewhat of variation on "you can lead a horse to water but you cannot make it drink" thus in some cases it can make sense for everybody not to force the proverbial horse  to the water place.

Answer (score 14):

We already do this more-or-less. It's not strictly the Tour but we show this page https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice which even has a check-box.

For reference, a link to the post (feature request) where this was introduced: [Show “how to ask” advice before a new user asks a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21512).