# There should be a "How to Ask" page tailored to math se.

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, help-center

The ["how to ask"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for this site includes very generic advice, it is be applicable to
almost all stack exchange sites.

But, for example, stackoverflow has their own ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page that is customized for that site.

I think our how to ask page should, too, be tailored more specifically to math stackexchange, to include problems we
generally face.

For example, we should add a "homework questions" section where we ask
the OP to show their work and ask specific questions as to where they're stuck.

Comment: A link explaining that you should use LaTeX / MathJax accompanying a relevant tutorial would be useful too - many new posts seem to appear all the time with no formatting.

Comment: This page is network-wide boilerplate.  It is not something which can be changed on a per-site level.  If you believe it is a major problem, I would suggest that you take it up on [meta.se] (though be warned that it has probably come up before, so start by *searching*).

Comment: Your "link" [2] doesn't go anywhere. Also, note that we do have https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question (but new users don't see it, unless other users point it out).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Actually, this link is provided to the users when asking a question. It is linked both in the modal window - which is shown to a users asking their first question - and in the "Draft your question" pane in the right sidebar to any user composing their question. 
The link in the text "Provide details. Share your research." goes to the question you've mentioned.
This was introduced as a result of this feature request: [Show "how to ask" advice before a new user asks a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21512).

Comment: Here you can find overview of the sites where the "Draft your question" pane is customized: [What site-specific changes can be made to the Ask Question page to help askers on that site write better questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058)

Comment: A related feature request on [meta.se]: [Allow moderators to add local guidance to the "how to ask a good question" page in the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280428) (from 2016, now closed as a duplicate of a more general discussion).

Comment: @Martin, thanks. I assumed new users didn't see it, because so many of them appear to be ignorant of its contents.