# The "Draft your question" pane still has some http (rather than https) links

Tags: bug, asking-questions, https

When a user asks a question, the pane with the title "Draft your question" is shown on the right.

Our site does not use the default version - it has been customized specifically for this site - it was done back in 2015: [Show "how to ask" advice before a new user asks a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21512). An overview of the sites where this pane is customized is given in this answer on Meta Stack Exchange: [What site-specific changes can be made to the Ask Question page to help askers on that site write better questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058#387652)

As you can check yourself by clicking on [ask question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), on Mathematics Stack Exchange this pane looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

I have reproduced the *current* text here.

> **Is your question about math?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>
> [Provide details](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). Share your research.
>
> Write an [interesting, specific title](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144) that summarizes the question.
>
> If your question is about this website, [ask it on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Here the text "Provide details" is a link to `http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960`, "interesting, specific title" is a link to `http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144` and "ask in on meta" is a link to `http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/`.

I did not find other non-https links in this pane.

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [Link to per-site meta in the sidebar/dropdown "Step 1: Draft your question" is not HTTPS and has the old format meta.*.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377064)